# What is the impact of disabling OPTIONS HTTP method on Apache Servers?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

In order to tackle OPTIONSBLEED exploit, I am thinking of various methods.

To disable OPTIONS HTTP method.
To apply CVE-2017-9798.
CVE-2017-9798 doesn't sound like a long term solution as it just protects server from .htaccess files's exploitation.

A more long term solution is to disable OPTIONS HTTP method on Apache Boxes.

Although, I am not sure what will be impacted from customer's standpoint had OPTIONS HTTP method was disabled ?

Please point me in right direction.

Answer (score 2):

The [recommended remediation](https://blog.fuzzing-project.org/60-Optionsbleed-HTTP-OPTIONS-method-can-leak-Apaches-server-memory.html) is to update your Apache server software.  Below is a quote from an Apache developer who [analyzed the vulnerability](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev//201709.mbox/%3CCACsi253RfX7OT5NhZCKRru2JpOKoscux%3DjzDzJOnbcF31XHmMw%40mail.gmail.com%3E):

> It is not possible to avoid this defect with untrusted/malicious
>   .htaccess authors without disabling .htaccess files, patching or
>   upgrading to version 2.4.28.

Disabling `OPTIONS` will not correct the problem.  In-fact it may actually make it worse, since the problem is triggered by having HTTP Methods in a `.htaccess` file that are not configured by the root webserver.